# How Set interface enforces no duplicates add and not preserving insertion order stipulations

Tags: java, collections

Q.1) As written in documentation of [AbstractSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) - "This class does not override any of the implementations from the `AbstractCollection` class." If it does not **override** or **change** `add(Object o)` or any other `Collection` interface contract implemented by `AbstractCollection` class, and merely inherits them and so as [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

**How do `HashSet` and other `Set` objects then enforce stipulations like no duplicate adding check or Hashtable way of inserting elements,** which is totally different to how `List` or other `Collection` objects can add elements.

Q.2) In doc, for [AbstractSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html), it is written, `AbstractSet` merely adds implementation for `equals` and `hashcode`. However, in **method details** part, it is mentioned `Object` class has done overriding `equals` and `hashcode` method. Does `AbstractSet` only inherit without doing any change to these two methods? If so, what is the importance of `AbstractSet` class? Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1: How does HashSet enforce duplicate checks?**

If you take a look at the implementation in *java.util.HashSet*, you'll see the following code:-

```
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

What happens is fairly simple; we use a private HashMap instance, which takes our provided value and inserts it as the key of the HashMap. The map's *PRESENT* value is never actually used or retrieved, but it allows us to use this backing map to verify whether or not the item exists in the Set.

If our provided value does not exist in the map, the call to *map.put()* will place the item in the map and return our object. Otherwise, the map remains unchanged and the method returns null. The HashMap is doing the hard work for the HashSet here.

This is different to the implementation provided by the *AbstractCollection* class, and hence the need to override.

**Q2: AbstractSet's use of equals() & hashCode()**

I think you have slightly misunderstood what AbstractSet is doing here. The purpose of AbstractSet is to provide a collection-safe implementation of equals and hashCode.

Equals checks are performed by verifying that we are comparing two Set objects, that they are of equal size, and that they contain the same items.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) o;
    if (c.size() != size())
        return false;
    try {
        return containsAll(c);
    } catch (ClassCastException unused)   {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The hashCode is produced by looping over the Set instance, and hashing each item iteratively:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode();
    }
    return h;
}
```

Any class extending from AbstractSet will use this implementation of equals() and hashCode() unless it overrides them explicitly. This implementation takes preference over the default equals and hashCode methods defined in *java.lang.Object*.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you provided are for Java 7, and I was checking the code of java 8 and I found the below so I think it isn't the same for java 7, still   you can use the same methodology of checking the code when the documentation isn't very clear for you: 
Q1: HashSet Overrides the add method in AbstractCollection you can easily check this if you open the HashSet code in some ide. If a parent doesn't override some methods doesn't mean its children can't do it.

Q2: Again by checking the code we notice that AbstractSet defines its own implementation of equals and hashCode methods.  It also overrides the removeAll method of AbstractCollection.

Comment: If you go to `HashSet` doc, `add` method details, it says **Overrides add in class `AbstractCollection`** what does that mean. What is the importance of `AbstractSet` calss then

Comment: @SwarupRanjanSahoo It serves multiple purposes. First to have a nice hierarchy of classes and also for some polymorphic behaviors I suspect. Also it overrides the equals and hashCode methods which are not re-defined in HashSet, so when they are called on HashSet it is the implementation in AbstractSet that is called. If you are not familiar with Abstract classes you should check it out and see how it is used. Not everything needs to have functionality to be useful, example: marker interface

Comment: This doubt is not because of `Abstract class`, rather **Overrides** part of documentation.